# When using MockMvc to test the controller, a parameter passing error occurred

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, testng, mockmvc

I am using MockMvc to test the controller. Regarding parameter import, I encountered a type mismatch problem. I tried all the json styles.But nothing works

This is my controller class::

```
package app.dnatask.controller;

import ......;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/API/scanresultconfigure")

public class ScanResultConfigureController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/queryScanResultList/{taskId}/{externalname}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public IBaseResult queryscanResultList(final HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable final String taskId, @PathVariable final String externalname, @RequestBody Map map) throws Exception {
        return runController(new IControllRunner() {
            public void run(IOutResult or, CheckResult cr) throws Exception {
                ......
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test class::

```
package app.dnatask.controller;

import ......

@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ScanResultConfigureController.class})
@ComponentScan(
        includeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
                        value = {ScanResultConfigureController.class})
        },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        lazyInit = true
)

public class ScanResultConfigureControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).dispatchOptions(true).build();
        System.out.println("UT starting.............");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void am() {
        System.out.println("UT ending.............");
    }

    @Test
    public void testQueryscanResultList() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        testMap.put("key1", "value1");
        testMap.put("key2", "value2");
        String requestJson = JSONObject.toJSONString(testMap);
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/API/scanresultconfigure/queryScanResultList/001/abc")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("map", requestJson)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

Error message::

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<415>
```

This is a project implemented by springmvc framework, I use TestNG for unit testing.

Comment: This kind of content type json questions is already asked several times on this site.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. Before I tried to search for related content but didn't find a suitable method, maybe I didn't search for the correct keywords, now I find the corresponding solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding my problem, the solution is as follows::

```
 MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                post("/API/scanresultconfigure/queryScanResultList/{taskId}/{externalname}", "123", "abc")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestJson)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();
```